# Select all ids in one table that match at least as many ids in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table structure like so

```
[movies]---<[movies_genres]>---[genres]---<[users_genres]>---[users]
```

I would like to query, given a `user.id`, only movies that share their genre with the `users_genres.genre_id`.

To be clearer, if a user likes the genres {sci-fi, action, and romance} but a movie is {sci-fi, action, and horror}, the movie should not be returned. However, if the movie is just {sci-fi} or {sci-fi, action} it should be returned. So if it has a genre not listed in the user's preferred genres, it should not be returned.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Something I tried

```
select movies_id from movies_genres mg
    where mg.genres_id not in (
    select genres_id from users_genres ug 
        where ug.users_id = 1
    )
```

**Edit2:**

Ok, I've fixed the above code and I think it seems to be working

```
select * from movies 
where movies.id not in (
    select movies_id from movies_genres mg
    where mg.genres_id not in (
        select genres_id from users_genres ug 
            where ug.users_id = 2
        )
)
```

I'm basically playing with subtracting sets (I think). This is all very new to me, so I'm not even that clear how the SQL is working here. Just that, if I can subtract one set from another and it ends up being empty as a result, it's a subset. This basically meets my requirements of the movie_genres being a subset of users_genres.

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

A `join` and `aggregation` should work between the tables:

```
select mg.movie_id
from user_genres ug left join
     movie_genres mg
     on mg.genre_id = ug.genre_id
where ug.user_id = ?
group by mg.movie_id
having count(*) = count(ug.genre_id);  -- do all match
```

EDIT:

If you want only exact matches, then a simple way is to create a list of genres and match on that:

```
select mg.movie_id
from (select mg.movie_id, group_concat(mg.genre_id order by mg.genre_id) as genres
      from movie_genres mg
      group by mg.movie_id
     ) mg join
     (select group_concat(ug.genre_id order by ug.genre_id) as genres
      from user_genres ug
      where ug.user_id = ?
     ) ug
     on mg.genres = ug.genres;
```

Comment: In my tests, this query returns a movie that has an extra genre not in the user's genre list. I will update my question to show something I've been trying out (but mine is also incorrect).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't actually want exact matches. I would like the a movie's genre set to be a subset of the a user genre set. So that a movie doesn't have to have all the genres from the user genres, but shouldn't have any that are not in the user genres. I'm sorry if I was not clear on this. However, I seem to have some code working (check my update).